# como enviar un json usando POSTMAN a controlador codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter, postman

tengo este json pero no llega al controlador estoy utilizando POSTMAN

Seleccione POST como metodo de envio  , en body  utilize raw y el formato json pero no llega me dice que no existe datos

url http://codeignitertuto.test/Registro/segmentob_208

```
    {"datos":"
{"id":"11421",
"nombre":"jghhj",
"correo":"fdfd@hotmail.com",
"telefono":"4444557671",
"estado":"1",
"modelo":"301",
"id_modelo":"2",
"tipo_ldp": "",
"aviso_privacidad":"1",
"utm": "",
"utm_campaign":"ghjhgj-ghj",
"utm_source":"ghj",
"utm_medium":"hj-hj",
"utm_content":"hj",
"utm_term":"",
"utm_completa":"",
"cotizacion":"0",
"prueba_manejo":"1",
"lead":""}"}
```

y lo quiero enviar a mi controlador php en codeigniter

```
public function segmentob_208(){

    if(!$_POST){
    echo "No existen datos que insertar";
    return;
    }

    $data = json_decode($_POST['datos']);       

    $estado = $data->estado;

    if( $estado==12 ){
            $estado=52;
            }

            if( $estado==18 ){
            $estado=58;
            }

            if( $estado==57 ){
            $estado=32;
            }

            if( $estado==35 ){
           $estado=34;
       }

    $correo_nuevo = $data->correo;

    $datos = array(
    'nombre'                => $data->nombre,
    'telefono'              => $data->telefono,
    'correo'                => $correo_nuevo,
    'consesionaria_id'      => $estado,
    'status'                => 1,
    'tipo_contacto'         => '',
    'update_status'         => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'origen'                => 'segmentob_208',
    'modelo'                => $data->id_modelo,
    'color_interes'         => '',
    'silueta'               => $data->id_modelo,
    'id_havas'              => $data->id,
    'fecha_havas'           => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'modelo_havas'          => $data->id_modelo,
    'utm_text'              => $data->utm,
    'utm_term'              => $data->utm_term,
    'utm_campaign'          => $data->utm_campaign,
    'utm_source'            => $data->utm_source,
    'utm_medium'            => $data->utm_medium,
    'utm_content'           => $data->utm_content,
    'califica_cotizacion'   => 1,
    'califica_prueba'       => 1,
    'comentario_calificacion'=>'',
    'digital'               => 1
    );

}
```

Comment: Pueden ser muchas cosas, desde la url que ocupas y no esté bien configurada (porque no va a ningún lado de tu proyecto en codeigniter) o el mal uso de POSTMAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero ayudar, creo que se el por que los datos no los recoge PHP.

JSON, vi que tienes comillas dobles en el objeto dentro de "datos", se los quité de la siguiente manera:

```
{
    "datos": {
        "id": "666",
        "nombre": "sadd",
        "correo": "fdfd@hotmail.com",
        "telefono": "31132",
        "estado": "1",
        "modelo": "301",
        "id_modelo": "2",
        "tipo_ldp": "",
        "aviso_privacidad": "1",
        "utm": "",
        "utm_campaign": "sdsad-dsad",
        "utm_source": "sad",
        "utm_medium": "dsa-asd",
        "utm_content": "dfs",
        "utm_term": "",
        "utm_completa": "",
        "cotizacion": "0",
        "prueba_manejo": "1",
        "lead": ""
    }
}
```

En archivo PHP, en la funcion json_decode le puse la opción true que hace que los objetos devueltos se conviertan en array asociativo y para acceder al array recogido, accedes como en un array normal:

```
public function segmentob_208()
{

    if (!$_POST) {
        echo "No existen datos que insertar";
        return;
    }

    $data = json_decode($_POST['datos'], true);

    $estado = $data['estado'];

    if ($estado == 12) {
        $estado = 52;
    }

    if ($estado == 18) {
        $estado = 58;
    }

    if ($estado == 57) {
        $estado = 32;
    }

    if ($estado == 35) {
        $estado = 34;
    }

    $correo_nuevo = $data['correo'];

    $datos = array(
        'nombre'                => $data['nombre'],
        'telefono'              => $data['telefono'],
        'correo'                => $correo_nuevo,
        'consesionaria_id'      => $estado,
        'status'                => 1,
        'tipo_contacto'         => '',
        'update_status'         => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'origen'                => 'segmentob_208',
        'modelo'                => $data['id_modelo'],
        'color_interes'         => '',
        'silueta'               => $data['id_modelo'],
        'id_havas'              => $data['id'],
        'fecha_havas'           => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'modelo_havas'          => $data['id_modelo'],
        'utm_text'              => $data['utm'],
        'utm_term'              => $data['utm_term'],
        'utm_campaign'          => $data['utm_campaign'],
        'utm_source'            => $data['utm_source'],
        'utm_medium'            => $data['utm_medium'],
        'utm_content'           => $data['utm_content'],
        'califica_cotizacion'   => 1,
        'califica_prueba'       => 1,
        'comentario_calificacion' => '',
        'digital'               => 1
    );
}
```

En el postman prueba en la sección x-www-form-urlencoded (Amplia la img si no se ve bien):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
NOTA: Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: gracias por la corrección en el objeto , sigue sin llegar  me indica No existen datos que insertar

Comment: ¿Sigue sin resolver el problema ?

Comment: gracias ya quedo y gracias por tu tiempo